# Amadeus flight body returns zero flights despite there being multiple valid flights that day. (dateWindow, timeWindow)

Tags: javascript, amadeus

Below is the post body for a request.

In response I'm getting an object with `data` containing an empty array, and a `meta` object with the property `length: 0`.

But there are flights available that day: https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhojagwIAhIIL20vMDRqcGwSCjIwMjMtMDUtMTRyBwgBEgNNQU4aI2oHCAESA01BThIKMjAyMy0wNS0xOXIMCAISCC9tLzA0anBscAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQE

I have previously had working post requests, however I have removed the originRadius, and destinationRadius options to restrict the airports.

In this case I'm going from all London airports (LON) to Manchester airport (MAN).

I'm expecting any flights +/- 3 days (I3D) and any time on those days.

```
{
"currencyCode": "USD",
"originDestinations": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "originLocationCode": "LON",
        "destinationLocationCode": "MAN",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2023-05-14",
            "dateWindow": "I3D",
            "time": "12:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "12H"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "originLocationCode": "MAN",
        "destinationLocationCode": "LON",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2023-05-19",
            "dateWindow": "I3D",
            "time": "12:00:00",
            "timeWindow": "12H"
        }
    }
],
"travelers": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
],
"sources": [
    "GDS"
],
"searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 7,
    "oneFlightOfferPerDay": true,
    "flightFilters": {
        "cabinRestrictions": [
            {
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "coverage": "ALL_SEGMENTS",
                "originDestinationIds": [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "connectionRestrictions": {
            "maxNumberOfConnections": 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit: This is how I'm requesting the flightOffers:

```
private async searchFlightOffers(flightSearchBody: FlightSearchBody): Promise<FlightOffersResponse> {

const accessToken = await this.getAccessToken();
const apiUrl = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers';

console.log(`Searching for flight offers between ${flightSearchBody.originDestinations[0].originLocationCode} to ${flightSearchBody.originDestinations[0].destinationLocationCode}...`, flightSearchBody)
console.log('Using access token: ' + accessToken)

try {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(flightSearchBody),
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.warnings) {
    console.warn('Warnings returned from flight search: ', data.warnings);
  }

  console.log(data)

  return data;
} catch (error: any) {
  console.error(`Failed to search for flight offers: ${error.message}`);
  throw error;
}
```

}

my `getAccessToken()` method is reliable, and if the access token were bad I would get an error message.

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the API?

Comment: @Pointy added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, you are using the test environment of the Amadeus API. This environment does not provide realtime data, instead it is "limited" and "cached". This is likely the reason behind the missmatch of the Amadeus API response and your search on Google.

Here you can find more information:

- https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/test-and-production-environments-for-amadeus-self-service-apis-
- https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/test-data/

Comment: Thanks, this is possibly the answer - however, I did manage to "fix" the problem by removing the 'time' and 'timeWindow' restrictions for my flight departure.... This is odd as my time and timeWindow should have captured the entire day, and therefore not restricted the number of flights.

Comment: Additionally I did deploy and test a production key, the production key also found 0 flights with time and timeWindow set, but did find ~49 flights without these options.